# How to retrieve all values from a parse class?

Tags: java, android, parse-platform

Ok, so I am making an app where users can make confessions anonymously. So what i have done is made a parse object called userPost. When the user clicks the send button it takes the text from EditTest1 and sends it to the parse cloud under the tag confession. I want to grab all the values from confession. How would i do that? To clarify, click this link: http://gyazo.com/5e9f3b38406efd358ad199003cc24cf1
See confession? I want to grab all the values under that tab.

heres the code;

```
package com.example.stemwhipser;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.GetCallback;
import com.parse.Parse;
import com.parse.ParseException;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
Button sendBtn;
EditText something;
TextView hey;
 public String some = "";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);             
    Parse.initialize(this, "sHBbzqwjHx96UgDYrAdllJxJCAa0BZCXiAa76cM0", "49ViM4lvJFuDIdzReDylofKN9t9GXi677NAbtFti");
    sendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    final EditText confession = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

    sendBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {          
          some = confession.getText().toString();          
          ParseObject userPost = new ParseObject("Post");
          userPost.put("confession",some.toString());          
          userPost.saveInBackground();

        }
     });

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you read parse documentation?

```
import com.parse.FindCallback;
import com.parse.ParseObject;
import com.parse.ParseQuery;
import com.parse.ParseException;
```

parse Code for select query

```
ParseQuery parseQuery = new ParseQuery("Post");
parseQuery.findInBackground(new FindCallback() {
@Override
public void done(List objects, ParseException e) {
    if (e == null) {
    // fetch your records here 
 for (final ParseObject objparse : objects) {
      objparse.get("confession").toString(),
  }
    }
    else
    {
        //parse error
    }
   }
}
```